# Python split a line using two delimiters "/" and " "

Tags: python, regex

I have the following data in a csv file:

```
 IDA/IDB/type/timestamp valueoftype

 A1/B1/a/1575033906 4
 A1/B1/b/1575033906 5
 A1/B1/c/1575033906 3
 A1/B2/a/1575033906 5
 A2/B3/a/1575033906 6
 A1/B2/b/1575033906 7
 A1/B2/c/1575033906 85
 A2/B3/b/1575033906 6
 A2/B3/c/1575033906 4
 .
 .
 .
 A1/B1/a/1575033909 5
 A1/B1/b/1575033909 6
 A1/B1/c/1575033909 4
```

I want to use a regular expression so that I can read each line of the file in order to split it based on two delimiters. In my case those delimiters are " " and "/". So in the end, I want to have this :

```
['A1','B1','a','1575033906','4']
```

Here is the code I used:

```
for line in f:
    print(line)
    x = re.split(r'[ /]+', line)
    print(x)
```

And the results it gives me is this:

```
 ['A1','B1','a','1575033906','4\n']
```

How could I exclude the "\n" character from getting into that last position?

Comment: `line.strip()` in your `re.split(...)` line. `x = re.split(r'[ /]+', line.strip())`

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy Thank you sir, it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strip` or `rstrip` it away:

```
x = re.split(r'[ /]+', line.strip())
```

If there's precious whitespace at the beginning of the line, use `rstrip` to strip from the right:

```
>>> ' w t\n'.rstrip()
' w t'
```